# How to get command line arguments in Ceylon?

Tags: ceylon

In a command line Java application you can get arguments through the `args` parameter:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

How can I do something similar in Ceylon? I tried copying the Java style:

```
shared void run(String[] args) {
```

but got an error since that is not allowed:

```
ceylon run: Cannot run toplevel method 'test.project.run': 
it should have no parameters or they should all have default values.
```

I've been reading the ceylon-lang.org tour but I haven't found the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the top-level [`process`](http://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/process.object.html) object in the language module.

```
String[] arguments = process.arguments;
String? argument = process.namedArgumentValue("name");
if (process.namedArgumentPresent("name")) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How did you know about the properties 'arguments' and 'namedArgumentValue' ?  I can't see them in the list of members: https://herd.ceylon-lang.org/modules/ceylon.process/1.3.3/members

Comment: You're looking at the `ceylon.process` module, which is distinct from and serves a different purpose than the `process` top-level object in the language module that I linked to in my answer.